# gulp-pleeeaseのremを10px基準にしたい場合の指定方法について

Tags: gulp

```
{
    rem: ["10px"]
}
```

と指定したのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。
うまく動作させるにはどう記述するのが正しいのでしょうか。

Comment: 現状バージョンアップされて問題ないようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

何が原因なのだろうと、ソースを探っていたら
原因となる箇所を発見しました。

どうやら
pleeease 2系のバグらしく、
現状3系がでているのでこっち側を使えば問題ありませんでした。

ただ現時点でgulp-pleeeaseでのpackage.jsonに記述してある内容が"^2.0.0"になっているため、
これを"^3.0.0"ににして再度"npm install"することで解決することが出来ました。

まだまだ出始め？で情報が少ないということも有り
autoprrefixerを使うほうが無難ということでしょうかね。

Comment: 自己解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers